# Why to test while we are using interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, tdd

I am pretty new to testing. So, I don't understand why to use testing while we can make use of the interface.

What interface does is almost similar to testing. So do we need to test the code of an interface itself?

Here is a code of an interface, please suggest how should I test it.

```
interface boardMeeting{
    get_team(): Team;
    get_partner(): Partner;
    get_secretary(): Secretary;
}
```

Thank YOU.

Comment: you should test code that implements this interface, to make sure that it conforms to what the interface defines.

Comment: You can't "test an interface" since its not a construct that exists outside of the typescript type-system. However you could, and should, test whatever object is implementing the interface.

Comment: So all I should check is the functionality of object implementing interface.